Sympy can't notice elementary algebraic identity: I - A*(A+I).inverse() == (A+I).inverse()
The following sympy code outputs False instead of True
from sympy import symbols, Identity, MatrixSymbol
d = symbols("d")
I = Identity(d)
A = MatrixSymbol("A", d, d)
print(I - A@(A + I).inv() == (A + I).inv())


Question. How to get sympy to identity that basic matricial equivalence and output True ?


Alas, == only tests for structural equality. To represent equality in Sympy one could use Eq, i.e
eq_expr = Eq(I - A@(A + I).inv(), (A + I).inv())


One then might test for equality by rewriting Eq as Add to convert the equation into a LHS - RHS form and check this evaluates to 0, i.e.
eq_expr.rewrite(Add).simplify()

However, in this case, Sympy can't simplify the expression further.
There's a further option to use equals but this won't work here since the matrix has a symbolic shape d.
One could perhaps use a substitution to evaluate the identity. E.g.
B = MatrixSymbol("B", d, d)
eq_expr.rewrite(Add).subs({I+A: B, A: B-I}).expand()

That said, I suspect you don't really need to prove equality but perhaps would like Sympy to utilize the identity in simplifying a more complex expression.
Take a look at the docs for further info around equals.
